# perl inline edit in perl script

Tags: perl

I have following line in my perl script (which I run from cshell)

```
system("perl -p -i -e 's/\+[a-z]+\+//g' $file1");
```

I expect it to delete all the words which are surrounded by + plus signs. Instead, I'm getting below error message.

> Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/+ <-- HERE [a-z]++/ at -e line 1.

What is happening? I gave backslashes, why then this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say `$file1` contains `-foo bar.txt`, the string literal

```
"perl -p -i -e 's/\+[a-z]+\+//g' $file1"
```

produces the string

```
perl -p -i -e 's/+[a-z]++//g' -foo bar.txt
                 ^      ^     ^   ^
                 |      |     |   |
                 +---- errors ----+
```

Don't create a shell command when you don't need to. Just launch `perl` directly.

```
system("perl", "-p", "-i", "-e", 's/\+[a-z]+\+//g', '--', $file1)
```

But why create a new process at all? You can use the following to do the exact same thing!

```
{
    local @ARGV = $file1;
    local $^I = '';
    while (<>) {
        s/\+[a-z]+\+//g;
        print;
    }
}
```

Or as a sub:

```
sub fixer {
    my $pat = shift;
    local @ARGV = @_;
    local $^I = '';
    while (<>) {
        s/$pat//g;
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's that double dash for ('--', $file1) ?  The other alternative looks rather lengthy. I need to do inline edit many times (5-10 times). Would it be better to write a sub-routine out of your code?

Comment: Marks the end of options. Fixes error #3. If you build the value in `$file1` yourself, and you know it doesn't start with `-`, the `--` isn't needed. If you accept arbitrary file names, removing `--` will cause the program to malfunction for some possible (but albeit rare) values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I need to do inline edit many times (5-10 times). Would it be better to write a sub-routine out of your alternative code?

Comment: @user13107, Sure, why not. Updated. You can even pass multiple file names to the sub.

Comment: Cool! I edited your sub so that it can take arbitrary patterns. `sub fixer {
    local $file = shift; local $pattern = shift;
    local $^I = '';
    while (<>) {
        s/$pattern//g;
        print;
    }
}
` @ikegami let me know if this seems fine.

Comment: @user13107, Updated to show how to accept a pattern and multiple file names.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the multiple argument version of `system`:

```
system("perl", "-p", "-i", "-e", 's/\+[a-z]+\+//g', $file1)
```

This avoids invoking the shell and having it re-interpret the command line.